# How to use $scope values from Angular included files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In Angularjs using ng-include im facing some trouble...

 Im having a single html form and including other html within it.

If this is my main.html..

```html
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">
<div ng-include src="'/Tab1.html'"></div>
 {{data.name}}
 <!--trying to use one of the Tab1 field but unable to fetch -->
<button type="submit" ng-click=save()>Save</button>
</div>
```

in Tab1.html

```html
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="data.name">
{{data.name}}<!--getting the value here-->
</div>
```

in my controller

```js
angular.module('app')

.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams','$rootScope' ,'$location', 
function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $rootScope ,$location){

$scope.save= function(){
console.log($scope.data);//undefined...
}

})
```

Must be minior mistake but not known where...*Thanks in advance for fixing!!*

Comment: I think, you don't need **ng-controller** in Tab1.html. And use **$scope.data** in console.log().

Comment: im not getting value {{data.name}} after including also ...changed $scope.data still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-include creates a child scope to acces the parent scope use $prarent

in Tab1.html

```
<div>
<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.data.name">
{{$parent.data.name}}<!--getting the value here-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.name">
    {{data.name}}<!--getting the value here-->
</div>
```

Remove controller in child div and it will take current scope;

also in controller use

```
$scope.data={name:""};
$scope.save= function(){
    console.log($scope.data);
}
```

and it will work;

Comment: hey i guess it will work if i call save function from tab1... bt im calling from main html where i included tab1... and i want {{data.name}} value in main html too...

Comment: add this in controller at top `$scope.data={name:""};` ; included file has parents scope, so it must work anyway